# Write a query and pass the predefined value

Tags: sql

First i write my query....

```
SELECT V.Country as Country, count(distinct MyNo) as CountData 
FROM dbo.details V 
WHERE country = 'india'
and (',' + ISNULL(replace(cateId,' ',''),'') + ','  like '%,31,%')
GROUP BY Country
```

I have a variable like @Id and want to replace like

```
(',' + ISNULL(replace(cateId,' ',''),'') + ','  like '%,@Id,%')
```

so any one help me how to do that and in ID i have the value in different record id now we assume is 31 so how to write that query

and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
like '%,' + cast(@Id as varchar(12)) + ',%'
```

If `@Id` is a `varchar` variable, you can omit the cast:

```
like '%,' + @Id + ',%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also write this as:

```
(',' + ISNULL(replace(cateId, ' ', ''), '') + ','  like replace('%,@Id,%', '@Id', @id))
```